# Default Keyrings Login Folder ( Deleted)

Tags: keyrings, gnome-keyring

To fix a password issue with Chrome I deleted the Login Folder using seahorse (Passwords and Keys)

It fixed the Chrome problem but caused major issues with another APP i need to use

How to I fix that, simply create a Login Folder ?

JF

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your other application requires the `Login` keyring and you had deleted it, you can simply create a new `Login` keyring.

1. Open *Seahorse* (*Passwords and keys*) and click the green **+** button.
2. Select "Password keyring" as item type to create.
3. You will be asked for a name, which should be exactly `Login`.
4. After that, you have to set a new password, which has to be equal to your account's password, so that it can get unlocked automatically when you log in to your Ubuntu account.

Now there should be a new `Login` keyring in the list. You can test if it unlocks properly by logging out of your Ubuntu account and back in. If everything worked, it should be unlocked then.